# Android Versions of Designer Board Games

Tags: board-game-adaptations

Is there a good place to find out about designer board games that have been converted to the Android platform?  I know about the standard popular ones like [Catan](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.exozet.android.catan&feature=search_result) and [Carcassonne](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.exozet.game.carcassonne&feature=search_result), but it seems like you have to perform the leg work of looking through BGG lists/internet searches way more for Android than iOS to find anything.

Comment: +1 for using my prefered term Designer board games (because the designers name is usually on the box)

Comment: @user1873 - "Designer Board Games" makes me think of genetically-tailored nanotech board games that adjust the rules based on your personality. That you play in a super-hip penthouse suite, in a sharp suit...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Boardgamegeek.com](http://boardgamegeek.com) has several geeklists with android versions listed.

[Android Games with Asynchronous Multiplayer](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/73371/android-games-with-asynchronous-multiplayer)

[Android versions of actual boardgames](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/72020/android-versions-of-actual-boardgames)

These are not the only ones, just the ones that stood out in the search results.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I hate BGG lists as it's a bit too much work to parse through them looking for new stuff. (Maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: You're unlikely to find a site with a better correlation between them. Truth is, the 'Geek works best when you subscribe to particular lists that interest you (and subscribe to nothing else), and use the new items feature. It then red-highlights new items in a geeklist for you. Parsing new stuff then is simple (unless you're red-blue colorblind).